# Overriding a specific view mode html.tpl.php template

Tags: 7, theming

How can I override the html.tpl.php template for only the "teaser" view mode of the "Article" content type?

I found this on the [Drupal 7 Template (Theme Hook) Suggestions](https://drupal.org/node/1089656) page on drupal.org page, but cannot see how to drill down to a specific view mode for a single content type.

> **html.tpl.php** base template: *html.tpl.php* The following are some examples of how you may override the base template:
>
> 1. html--internalviewpath.tpl.php
> 2. List item
>
> html--node--id.tpl.php
>
> See [html.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--html.tpl.php) in the Drupal API documentation for more
>   information.

Will I need to implement a page preprocess hook to accomplish this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I am sure you know, the *teaser* view is only/mostly used when a list of nodes are put together, eg, the promoted to front page listing, a View listing, etc.

So, let's say you have a View page listing the most recent Articles, and it's sitting at `www.yourhost.com/recent/articles`, you could override the `html.tpl.php` there by creating a `html--recent-articles.tpl.php` file in your theme and modifying it accordingly.

Views itself also allows the use of node templates when a node is presented in a listing; if that is what you are needing or requiring, the template files there are along the lines of `node-view-VIEWNAME.tpl.php.`

Answer (score 1):

Though Jimajamma is right, unless you're doing something insanely abstract, I wouldn't recommend doing a template override to simply edit a "teaser".

If you need more control of your displays, use [Display Suite](http://drupal.org/project/ds), maybe even combined with DS Extras if you need more functionality.